# ASUS X553M Laptop Has Trouble Booting Live CD/Installing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, asus

I've already read the other forum posts either on a similar issue or my exact same model and found nothing that helped. Basically, my issue is this:

I downloaded the iso, used pendrivelinux to make a live USB, and selected it as my boot option. Check. But when I check the disc for defects, I found two. Alright, understandably the boot failed. But the weird part is that it didn't always fail. It succeeded once, installed ubuntu, but then I couldn't boot up the freshly installed OS upon reboot. I was actually able to repeat that multiple times, to the final product of no working OS. Some of the errors I got were, if I can remember correctly (recent attempts haven't even gotten there): "BGRT unresolved at 0 (expecting 1)" and "PCI INT A failed: No GSI"

But then I tried with a fresh burn with a clean CD rom, 0 defects found, and couldn't even boot that liveCD either. It hung at the purple screen every time. I'd like to think that my laptop, which can run Windows 10, would be able to run Ubuntu, but it doesn't seem able to. Anyone know any fixes or at least a more specific direction than I've been able to find looking at the forum posts for those errors?

Comment: Please include info about your laptop, specifically what graphics card you have. Also, have you tried creating the media with any program other than pendrivelinux, such as [LiLi Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try in advanced bios settings changes to "Windows 7" ( default is Windows 8 ). If you have trouble on UEFI, just turn off UEFI. To make sure boot from USB disable XHCI for a while until you got your ubuntu installed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to BIOS and disable Secure Boot.
2. Enable cms.
3. Download any Linux weekly iso file. Make sure you download the weekly distribution because in my case I am only able to install weekly Linux distributions.
4. Make USB flash drive bootable with [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).
5. Keep the USB flash drive plugged in and reboot. Go to BIOS and select boot option 1: <flash drive>:UEFI.
6. Install and done.